# Issues with connecting to oracle database with SSIS

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, ssis, database-connection

When setting up an ado.net connection to an oracle database/server using an ado.net oracleClient data provider setup, I get the following error:

> Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider.
>   Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw
>   BadImageFormatExxception. This problem will occur when running in 65
>   bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.

However, I have already set the project property of `run64bitRunTime = False`.

When I try to set up the connection using the OLE DB provider for Oracle, I get the following error:

> Oracle client and networking components not found. These components
>   are supplied by oracle corporation and are part of oracle version
>   7.3.3 or later client software installation. Provider is unable to function until these components are installed.

However, the components *are* installed.

Perhaps it's an issue with how I'm setting up my connections? From my tnsnames.ora file, my connection format is the following (I've changed actual address names):

```
server_usr.world =
(description =
(address = (protocol = TCP)(host = some.address.org)(port=1571))
(connect_data = (server = dedicated)(service_name = server_usr.something.org))
```

In both the examples above, I was inputting some.address.org into the server address. Is there a type of connection where I can put in the whole connection string listed above?

Comment: There is crucial information missing in this post, what is the oracle server version, what is the client version, which platform? what errors are raised/returned

Comment: Which Oracle Client did you install? The 32-bit or the 64-bit version?